# Does every finite $CW$ complex have the homotopy type of a smooth manifold? How about infinite $CW$ complexes?

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, cw-complexes

Let M be a smooth manifold. I was wondering if every finite or infinite CW complex has the homotopy type of a smooth manifold because it seems way easier to compute De Rham cohomology groups than homology groups.

If the answer to the questions are yes, is it hard to find a smooth approximation of a CW complex?

Comment: Isn't it easier to compute Cellular Homology than cohomology if you know the cell structure of the space?

Comment: Well in some cases it might be easier to compute cellular homology. But I rather work with the Mayer Vietoris sequence with cohomology vector spaces than with abelian groups.

Comment: I just mean that if you know ahead of time the CW structure this gives you exactly the information of the chain complex for computing the homology. So, aren't the CW structure and the homology equivalent pieces of information? (Forgive me if I'm making some stupid mistake, I don't really think about CW stuff that often)

Comment: @AlekosRobotis No you aren't making a stupid mistake. I think you are right that it would be easier to just compute the homology groups using cellular homology. I am still curious if CW structures can be approximated by smooth manifolds.

Comment: For the question about infinite CW complexes the answer is no. You can take $\Bbb{CP}^\infty$ which will have cohomology in arbitrarily high dimensions, so this definitely does not have the homotopy type of a manifold (in the traditional sense). The finite CW complexes question seems a little bit more delicate.

Comment: If you have a finite CW complex then I think you can take a tubular neighborhood (suitably defined for this setting) and at least get a manifold with boundary. If we don't allow for a boundary, the cohomology of closed manifolds tends to be constrained in certain ways, e.g. for compact oriented manifolds the interplay of Poincare duality with universal coefficients reduces the total number of independent Betti numbers quite a bit. I don't know much at all about the story for open and/or non-orientable manifolds though, so you might find and interesting answer there.

Comment: Here is an obstruction: [the fundamental group of any topological manifold with or without boundary, compact or non-compact is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384689/is-it-true-that-a-second-countable-topological-space-which-has-an-universal-cove). This is due to the second countability of a topological manifold. I hope finite CW-complex means finite-dimensional CW-complex.

Comment: Have you thought about the case of.the figure eight?

Comment: Every 
wedge 
of 
finitely 
many 
spheres 
can 
be 
viewed 
as 
a 
deformation 
retract 
of 
an 
open 
subset 
of 
a 
sufficiently 
high-dimensional $\Bbb R^n$. For $\Bbb S^1\lor \Bbb S^1$ one can do with $\Bbb R^2$. Actually, $\Bbb R^2\backslash\{\text{two points}\}\simeq \Bbb S^1\vee \Bbb S^1$.

Comment: I hope number of points where a compact CW-complex fails to be locally Euclidean is finite, so considering some kind of regular neighborhoods at those points we can find an open subset of a sufficiently high-dimensional $\Bbb R^n$. And non-compact CW-complex has already done: $\Bbb CP^\infty$ or $\Bbb RP^\infty$.

Comment: The point of the figure eight is that it shows you need to allow either boundaries and/or noncompact manifolds. It also shows how to do this in general: embed in a euclidean space and take a small neighborhood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

If $X$ is a *finite CW-complex*, then in general there does not exist a *compact manifold* which is homotopy equivalent to $X$.

It clearly suffices to consider connected CW-complexes because we can argue componentwise.

So let $X$ be a finite connected CW-complex of dimension $n$ such that its $n$-th homology group with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_2$ has the property $H_n(X;\mathbb Z_2) \ne \mathbb Z_2$. An example is $S^n \vee S^n$. Assume that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a compact manifold $M$ of dimension $m$. It must clearly be connected.
A well-known fact (see e.g. Hatcher Theorem 3.26) is that $H_k(M;\mathbb Z_2) = 0$ for $k > m$ and $H_m(M;\mathbb Z_2) = \mathbb Z_2$. Hence $n \ge m$ is impossible. But also $n < m$ is impossible because in that case $H_m(X) = 0$.

This leaves open whether there always exists a *non-compact* manifold $M$ which is homotopy equivalent to $X$. In the example $X  = S^1 \vee S^1$ this is the case.

**Update:**

In Moishe Kohan's answer you see that the answer is "yes" for finite (connected) CW-complexes and non-compact (connected) manifolds. Note that if $X$ is homotopy equivalent to such $M$, then necessarily $\text{dim} M  >  \text{dim} X$ provided $H_{\text{dim} X}(X) \ne 0$. See Hatcher Proposition 3.29.

Answer (score 9):

For finite complexes - yes, for infinite complexes in general - no.

1. Why yes: First, each finite CW  complex $W$ is homotopy-equivalent to a finite simplicial complex $C$. (This should be in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology.") Next, each finite simplicial complex embeds as a subcomplex in a simplex which then embeds in some ${\mathbb R}^n$ as a part of a triangulation of the latter. Now, you have a subcomplex $X$ of a triangulated ${\mathbb R}^n$. Take the regular neighborhood $N_X$ of $X$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$: It will be homotopy-equivalent to $X$ and a compact (PL) submanifold with boundary. (Both should be in Rourke and Sanderson's "PL topology".)  Lastly, take the interior of $N_X$. This is your manifold.

With a bit more work, this proof extends to the case of countable CW complexes of finite dimension. (The main difference is that you first prove the existence of a finite-dimensional locally finite simplicial complex $C$ homotopy-equivalent to $W$, this is in Hatcher's book. Then the simplicial version of Whitney's theorem gives you a proper embedding as a subcomplex in ${\mathbb R}^n$. The rest is the same.)

2. Why no (even for countable complexes). Consider the wedge of spheres of all dimensions. The resulting CW complex $X$ has the property that
   $$
   H_k(X)\ne 0, \forall k\in {\mathbb N}. 
   $$
   However, if $M$ is an $m$-dimensional manifold then $H_k(M)=0$ for all $k>m$. (This is a consequence of the Poincare duality, again is in Hatcher's book.)

As another, finite-dimensional, example, take $X$ to be an uncountable set with discrete topology, or (if you prefer a connected example), an uncountable wedge of circles. Then $H_1(X)$ has uncountable rank which is impossible for a manifold. (I am assuming that *manifolds* are required to be 2nd countable, which is a standard assumption, although some people disagree.)

Comment: Is the manifold $N_X$ smoothable?

Comment: @Mathlover Yes, it is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I see, sorry. my bad

Comment: Your answer indicates that a countable $n$-dimensional CW complex $X$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^N$ for some $N$. Do you know any bounds on $N$? If you further assume $X$ is locally compact (equivalently, locally finite), then $N = 2n + 1$ suffices, see Theorem A of *CW-Complexes and Euclidean Spaces* by Fritsch & Piccini, available [here](https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/4524/1/4524.pdf).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: I was thinking only about proper  maps. For improper ones, it is still $2n+1$, I think, but they are not very useful.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese The countable infinite wedge of circles is not metrizable and thus does not embed into any $\mathbb R^n$. However, each countable CW complex $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a locally finite and countable CW-complex $X'$. See Fritsch & Piccini Proposition 2.2.5. The proof shows that if $dim X = n$, then one can achieve $dim X' \le n+1$.